# Can I have multiple classes in one file in MXML?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I have a classB that will only be used inside classA. However, classA is written as mxml, not actionscript code. Is it possible to nest classes in MXML or add another class after the root tag in the same .mxml file?
Clarification: I want both classes written in MXML within the same file, but I couldn't find anything in the Adobe documentation that specified how.

Comment: Can you provide more of an example?  It depends if your classes are view based or not and what's their purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't define two classes in one MXML file, but you can have the same package (namespace) for both classes and make classB `internal`, so its only visible for classes within that package.

Comment: I think this answer is slightly incomplete.  You cannot have two classes in an MXML file.  But, you can have two classes in a single ActionScript file.  It's rare, but does show up at times.  Take a look at the Flex 4 VerticalLayout class as a sample.  Also, I didn't know of a way to specify 'internal' in an MXML file; which is what the original poster was asking about.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com The OP stated, the classA is written in MXML and classB has to be internal, and he did not mentioned this has to be MXML as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the [fx:Component](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mxml/component.html) tag that allows you to define a new MXML document within an existing MXML document:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:local="*">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Component className="MyMXMLClass1">
            <s:Group>
                <s:Button label="MyMXMLClass1" />
            </s:Group>
        </fx:Component>
        <fx:Component className="MyMXMLClass2">
            <s:Group>
                <s:Button label="MyMXMLClass2" />
            </s:Group>
        </fx:Component>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:VGroup>
        <local:MyMXMLClass1 />
        <local:MyMXMLClass2 />
    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

If multiple levels of inheritance are required in the nested classes, and alternative to **<fx:Component>** (mentioned in a previous answer) is to use **<fx:Library>** for example:

```
<fx:Library>
    <fx:Definition
        name="MyClass"
        >
        <s:Group>
        ...
        <s:/Group>
    </fx:Definition>
</fx:Library>

...
<!-- Use MyClass later in the file. -->
<fx:MyClass ... />
```

The **<fx:Library>** must be at the top of the MXML file.  This syntax allows for several nested class definitions in a row, and each can extend the previous via inheritance.